# csvsimple causing page with \TRP1

Tags: csvsimple

[image]I was successfully using the csvsimple package with longtable and booktabs to read in a csv and make a table out of it. All of a sudden, any import of csvsimple causes this weird page to pop up as the first page of my document. Has anyone else encountered this before, or have any idea why this error wasn't occurring originally, but started to after I edited some of the text of the document? Any help would be so appreciated. I've attached a picture of the page that pops up when I use the csvsimple import, and I have confirmed that this is what's causing this weird page. Removing the import gets rid of the weird page.

Comment: that is something from the transparent package. But why you get is, it impossible to say without a small complete example.

Comment: It's strange because I'm not using the transparent package at all. And I can't seem to duplicate the result in a fresh project. My project is an unpublished manuscript, so I can't upload it either.

Comment: well check the log-file. It should show if transparent is loaded or not.

Comment: Yep, transparent definitely isn't loaded. I tried tossing it in there to see if it would help, but no luck. Still the weird page at the top.

Comment: show at least the (full) log file. Upload it somewhere if needed.

Comment: Full log file is uploaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vFC6cL1wPaV98WY7r7pyI3CVcQD_q8pC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It contains the line "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/transparent/transparent.sty".

Comment: You also get an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain`, and you shouldn't ignore errors. Add `\usepackage{pgfsys}` to your document.

Comment: That last import fixed it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You get an error

```
! Undefined control sequence. \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs ...urce@extgs@plain
```

This means that you don't load enough of pgf/tikz to make it compatible with the transparent package. See also https://github.com/ho-tex/transparent/issues/3.

Add at least `\usepackage{pgfsys}` to your document.